# Add Maps.jar to project

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I want to add maps.jar to my android project.
I download 'Google Apis' from SDK Manager,
but when i open a new 'Android Application Project' , I don't have option to choose target,
so i can't add Google Apis.
how can I solve it?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is little bit confusing. Why you want to add Maps.jar? Do you want to add Maps to your application?

New Maps API is part of Google Play Services. You have to download it from the SDK Manager. Then if for example you are using Eclipse, import this newly downloaded library project in to Eclipse and then add it to your project.